# Archipack: when adding a window to a wall with wood cladding, the window is at the wrong depth

Tags: modeling, add-on, archipack-add-on

when adding a window to a wall system using wood cladding, the window is by default at a depth of 0.09. The cladding hides most of the window (see image below). Changing the depth to 0.10 resolves the issue and the window is now visible.

However, when adding a new window, the old window (and others) default back to 0.09. Very frustrating.

I am using Blender 2.81a. Archipack 2.2.4

Anyone else had this issue?

[image: Archipack window hidden by wall cladding]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the hole geometry generation on such walls with small thickness.

Window depth is the same as wall width parameter and always must keep in synch with wall.

Either increase wall width or set window "Offset" to 0.06 (or play with this value) should be able to fix your issue.

Comment: Can't believe I did not try increasing wall width. That worked perfectly Stephen, thanks so much. FYI I had the width at 0.09m. Increasing to 0.1m worked.